# Marketplace that only accepts first-party NFTs to be sold

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721, nft

There are two contracts:

- ERC721 NFT contract (enables minting, etc)
- Marketplace contract (has a sell function and buy function)

When somebody calls the function to put a NFT for sale in the marketplace contract, I want it to only permit NFTs that were created in the aforementioned NFT contract. If someone tries to sell an unrelated NFT using that marketplace contract, he should be denied.

How can I do this?